# How to install WordPress on nested subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, installation

How do I install WordPress on the nested subdomain (ex:  project1.dev.website.com)?

I just get a white screen, but when I edit the `index.php` to include `echo "Test";` it appears on screen.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

echo "Test";
```

This code outputs:

> Output: Test

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I did change the image to code.
It's a fresh WordPress installation(i was not able to access the install screen).
The errors are on, but the file is empty(the error log)

Comment: Yes, i got an error. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"Test"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/wpaco/or.dev.wpa.co.il/index.php on line 20

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, have a wonderful day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180894/discussion-between-andrey-and-kirk-beard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your wp-config.php look like?
Btw. You don't need the installation wizard. You can install WordPress by configuring the database in wp-config.

Comment: Thank you, I did create wp-config.php(did copy code from wp-config-sample.php). Did edit it with my database details and the installation worked!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

1. Create new PHP file "wp-config.php"
2. Open "wp-config-sample.php" copy all the code and paste it into "wp-config.php"
3. now start editing "wp-config.php" with your database details
4. get security Keys from https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
5. DONE!


   Thanks to [Kenny Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950390/kenny-fox) for the help.

   Editing wp-config.php(full documentation about working with wp-config.php): https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php